# Does heredoc output variables which contains quotes?

Tags: php, html, variables, double-quotes, heredoc

I am using this:

```
$variable = "Name is \"Bob\"";
$message = <<<EOF
    <input type="text" value="$variable">
EOF;
```

And the result is :

[image]

Actually, this is synthetic example and I am working with db. But I tried: this synthetic example works (to simulate problem, actually it shows that what I am doing is not working).

Comment: Did you look at the page source? What you'll see is `<input type="text"  value="Name is "Bob"">`, so the PHP code is doing exactly the right thing, but the HTML is broken.

Comment: So the answer is yes, the heredoc will retain the quotes in the variable.

Comment: @Michael Berkowski: Backslashes have no special meaning in HTML - quotes are always encoded as `&quot;`.

Comment: @BoltClock or using the hex code `&#39;`

Comment: @BoltClock yeah, I typed some nonsense up there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are generating invalid HTML:

```
<input type="text" value="Name is "Bob"">
```

Please use [htmlspecialchars()](http://php.net/htmlspecialchars) to encode `$variable` before insertion.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the quotes will appear in the HTML.

Since the quotes will end the attribute value, you'll make the HTML invalid.

You need to make the variable HTML-safe with `htmlspecialchars()`.

Answer (score 1):

A heredoc is just a convenient shortcut for a  multi-line echo. It doesn't care WHAT'S in the string, it'll just be output.

There is NO difference between the following two constructs:

```
$foo = "A string with an \" embedded quote";

echo <<<EOL
Hello, $foo, how are you
EOL;

echo "Hello, $foo, how are you";
```

The only real difference is that you don't have escape quotes in the rest of the string:

```
echo <<<EOL
This is a "quoted phrase" within a sentence
EOL;

echo "This is a \"quoted phrase\" within a sentence";
```

Comment: Mhm. So it is better to encode all data with quotes before adding to the db, right? For example with `&quot;`, right? I mean, I have to use `htmlspecialchars()` before adding to the database, right?

Comment: hell NO! (pardon my french). htmlspecialchars is **USELESS** for database purposes. You need to read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php

Comment: Hm. I already using pdo. I don't have problems with adding data to the base. As I realized now, data is storing in database with quotes. Like `Some "name" data`, not `Some &quot;name&quot; data`. I have to store data in 2nd format, right? PDO, probably, as I use it doesn't do it, does it? [How I use pdo?](http://i.gyazo.com/5739150374fcce505c8bb5eea6879d9b.png). [Results of that in database](http://i.gyazo.com/eba434cebf901c4331a00e2f3e546fbd.png).

Comment: no. the db doesn't care how you encode your quotes. it DOES care how you get those quotes into the db in the first place.